# the unthinkable: use of Metafont for greek minion letters in black board style

Tags: greek, metafont, blackboard, alphabet

would it be possible to create our own greek letters in black board style from the Minion family using Metafont? It is just a matter of adding a vertical bar somewhere...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bev explained what to do if you have the `mf` file. Even if there isn't, you don't actually have to start from scratch. What you should have is a `tfm` file that contains the font metrics and a `pfb` file containing the actual glyphs (I'm assuming you have postscript type 1 fonts). You can just copy the original `tfm` file to `blackboard.tfm`; no change in the font metrics. Working with the `pfb` is more involved. I did this once and will try to recollect what you need.

First of all, you need to translate the `pfb` into something human readable. I did this with [t1utils](http://www.lcdf.org/type/#t1utils), e.g.

```
t1disasm minion.pfb > blackboard.raw
```

In the `raw` file you'll find the glyph descriptions, and they contain lots of stuff like `vhcurveto`, `rrcurveto` and so on. The latter describes a bezier curve, as far as I recollect. You can just experiment with these things to get the hang of it. Make a few edits, and make a new `pfb` file with

```
t1asm blackboard.raw > blackboard.pfb
```

Then put the `tfm` file into `texmf/fonts/tfm/blackboard/` and the `pfb` file into `texmf/fonts/type1/blackboard/`. Now I'm stumbling: You also need to create a font description in an `fd` file and a font map entry in a `map` file. At the moment I don't find what I did there; I hope someone else can help out.

Comment: :) The last (not) described step seems challenging! the blackboard.raw is a vector or raster format? Thanks

Comment: @pluton: It's some postscript type vector format. When I find time I might find out how the last step works.

Comment: Isn't `.pfa` the ascii format (corresponding to the binary `.pfb`)? I fought with fonts once. They won.

Comment: @TH.: `pfa` is ascii, but not human readable (unless you're capable of disassembling assembler code using just a hex editor).

Comment: @Hendrik - thanks for correcting my too hasty assertion. I don't really play with fonts anymore, so I bow to your superior know-how. But this has made me want to dig out my years-ago attempt to metafont-ize non-mf fonts. And for all those horror-stricken good-citizens out there, I'm also a good-citizen too and wasn't trying to steal proprietary fonts. Not my thing.

Comment: @Hendrik: Ah, okay. I don't believe I ever actually tried to read them.

Comment: @Hendrik: don't you need to mentally decrypt the code before mentally disassembling it?

Comment: @SamB: Ummh, _what?_ I think I know what you're alluding to, but what do you mean with "decrypt"?

Comment: @Hendrik: "A Type 1 font program consists of a clear text (ASCII) portion, and an encoded and encrypted portion." -- p. 1 (which software sees as p. 7) of the [Adobe Type 1 Font Format](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/font/T1_SPEC.PDF) spec.

Comment: @SamB: Errmmm ... ah, OK, now I understand what you mean. I didn't know about the encryption. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, although it would be difficult if the minion family (which I'm not familiar with) isn't done in metafont (i.e. doesn't already have an 'mf' file.)

If it *does* have an 'mf' file, you would just have to get the minion 'mf' file, copy it over to 'blackboard.mf' (or whatever) and edit it putting your changes in for each glyph. Then you would compile it, install it, and use it like any other font.

Metafont has a bad rep, but it's actually kinda fun. I made a letterhead logo in metafont once that I still use.

It's a little more work (actually a lot more work) if there is not minion.mf. Then you'd have to start from scratch in metafont. This would involve taking each minion glyph, projecting it somehow onto a grid, and use the metafont functions to draw the glyph using the grid/glyph templet as a guide. Then do the compile/install etc. stuff.

You could also write a program to do that for you, which I started to do once, but got busy on other stuff.

Comment: The only metrics that I have or .otf, I think but I can try to play between formats. As for metafont, the created font is in a vector or raster format? That's my fear. Thanks. What about using fontforge?

Comment: Well, the answer is sorta both. MF is basically a mathematical description of how to move a pen (of your description also) to draw things. So the mf file is scalable. But when compiled and installed they are bitmaps. You draw one description for each glyph, then tell it what size you want your compiled fontset to be.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I recall that there may be some parameters that change with scaling, i.e. some parts of some glyphs look better in 14.4 pt if the base is relatively thicker, etc.

Comment: @bev: I think that what you wrote in your first comment is only half of the truth. More than a decade ago it was standard that you compiled `mf` files to bitmaps, but nowadays it's not really desired anymore to use bitmap fonts. Somehow they managed to make postscript fonts out of the `mf` files, but I don't know the details.

Comment: @pluton: If you have `otf` files, then [these sourceforge tools](http://ttf2pt1.sourceforge.net/) might help you to produce `pfb` files; from those you can also extract the `tfm`, I think.

Comment: @Hendrik - Thanks for the correction. I never used metafont for making fonts. I used it to make logos, letterheads, icons, things like that. So I never really investigated too closely how to compile mf files into non-bitmaps. Bitmaps were fine for my purposes. But, I'm happy to hear it is possible now to make ps fonts. Metafont was my first experience with that method of creating a picture (using mathematical functions to describe a path for a pen to travel), and I really loved it.